# How do I access the other Object in Java?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have two classes one Customer and Account. In the Customer class I have the name of the customer and the accounts he has. The accounts are in a array:

```
private Account accounts[] = new Account[2];
```

In the beginning of the program the savings account will be set up:

```
public Customer(){
    account[0] = new Account("savings"); 
}
```

where the constructor of the Account class is:

```
public Account(String name){
     this.name = name;
}
```

and I have a method in Customer to add a credit account:

```
private void addAccount(){
    account[1] = new Account("credit");
}
```

and now a I have to transfer money from savings to credit in Account class

How do I access the two different accounts in Customer class. I have tried but failed with NullpointerExceptions

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide more code using Customer and Account objects? Highlight the line where NullPointerException is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method could look like this:

```
// addAccount method must already have been called!
private void transferFromSavingsToCredit(double amount) {
    accounts[0].balance -= amount;
    accounts[1].balance += amount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Account` class:

You should have a field call `Balance` that tracks the amount you have in that Account.

Then In your `Customer` Class :

You should have a method called `transfer(Account A, Account B,int amount)` then in this Class you should have logic in which if money is transferred from Account A to Account B , you shall subtract amount from Account A balance and add it to Account B balance.